# md-datepicker seems like not recognizing the md-max-date attribute

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material, maxdate

I am trying to set a max checkout date but my md-max-date is not working somehow. Codes below

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="model.checkInDate" md-min-date="today" ng-change="changeDate()" required md-hide-icons="calendar" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>

<md-datepicker ng-model="model.checkOutDate" md-min-date="model.checkInDate" md-max-date="model.maxCheckOutdate" ng-change="changeNight()" required md-hide-icons="calendar"></md-datepicker>

ChangeDate: function (checkInDate, night) {
                var model = {
                    checkOutDate: null,
                    tomorrow: null,
                    minCheckIndate: null,
                    maxCheckOutdate: null
                };

                model.checkOutDate = new Date(checkInDate).addDays(night);
                model.tomorrow = new Date(checkInDate).addDays(1);
                model.minCheckIndate = new Date(checkInDate).addDays(-1);
                model.maxCheckOutdate = new Date(checkInDate).addDays(60);
                console.log(model.maxCheckOutdate, "max date");

                return model;
            },
```

Why did I get this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the model to your scope. The changeDate function is returning the model, but where is it being bound?

Without binding it, there is no "model" available to the template scope.

Instead of `var model =...` try `$scope.model =...`, depending how you have your controller setup.